# Better way to query ranges in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, union

I have the following query

```
SELECT  0.0, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.0
UNION
SELECT  0.1, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.1
UNION
SELECT  0.2, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.2
UNION
SELECT  0.3, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.3
UNION
SELECT  0.4, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.4
UNION
SELECT  0.5, count(*) FROM tbl_a where value >=  0.5;
```

this works perfecty fine and I get the result i was hoping for, but its a pain to maintain and extend

I tried with grouping like so

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN value >= 0.5 THEN 0.5
        WHEN value >= 0.4 THEN 0.4
        WHEN value >= 0.3 THEN 0.3
        WHEN value >= 0.2 THEN 0.2
        WHEN value >= 0.1 THEN 0.1
        WHEN value >= 0.0 THEN 0.0
        END as mag,
        count(*) as numberOfCases
FROM tbl_a
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN value >= 0.5 THEN 0.5
        WHEN value >= 0.4 THEN 0.4
        WHEN value >= 0.3 THEN 0.3
        WHEN value >= 0.2 THEN 0.2
        WHEN value >= 0.1 THEN 0.1
        WHEN value >= 0.0 THEN 0.0
END
ORDER BY MAG
```

but then the result does not give me group with 0 value as well as not accumulated,

for example when I state `value >= 0` the result should include all values that are higher or equal to 0.0 but it does not an it includes only those with 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the bounds into a sub-query:

```sql
WITH lower_bounds (lower_bound) AS (
  SELECT 0.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.5 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT lower_bound,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   tbl_a
       INNER JOIN lower_bounds
       ON (value >=  lower_bound)
GROUP BY lower_bound;
```

You could also write it using a collection:

```sql
SELECT b.COLUMN_VALUE AS lower_bound,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   tbl_a t
       INNER JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)) b
       ON (t.value >=  b.COLUMN_VALUE)
GROUP BY b.COLUMN_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are your ranges arbitrary?  If you just want to round `value` to the nearest tenth and then aggregate

```
select round( value, 1 ),
       count(*)
  from table_a a
 group by round( value, 1 );
```

Assuming you want arbitrary ranges, though, I'd create a `range` table or simulate one with a CTE depending on whether you want to apply the same set of ranges to different queries.

```
with ranges as (
  select 0.1 lower_bound, 0.2 upper_bound from dual
  union all
  select 0.2, 0.3 from dual
  union all
  select 0.3, 0.4 from dual
  union all
  select 0.4, 0.5 from dual
  union all
  select 0.5, 999 from dual
)
select r.lower_bound, count(*)
  from table_a a
       join ranges r
         on a.value >= r.lower_bound
        and a.value <  r.upper_bound
 group by r.lower_bound
```

Comment: This does not give the same result as the OP's solution has no upper bound for the range.

Comment: @MT0 - True.  Normally there are reasonable upper bounds that one can choose.  You could also declare an upper or lower bound `null` and code for that in the join.  You can also avoid duplicating the upper bound of one range and the lower bound of the other (assuming the intention is to have continuous ranges) but that adds complexity to the query.

Comment: the column only contains values with 1 digit, that allows me to use the upper query to simplify the select, the range would be from .5 upper bound to -4.0 lower bound

Answer (score 1):

You can use your basic query structure with window functions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN value >= 0.5 THEN 0.5
             WHEN value >= 0.4 THEN 0.4
             WHEN value >= 0.3 THEN 0.3
             WHEN value >= 0.2 THEN 0.2
             WHEN value >= 0.1 THEN 0.1
             WHEN value >= 0.0 THEN 0.0
        END) as mag,
       COUNT(*) as numberOfCases,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(value)) as cumulative_numberOfCases
FROM tbl_a
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN value >= 0.5 THEN 0.5
               WHEN value >= 0.4 THEN 0.4
               WHEN value >= 0.3 THEN 0.3
               WHEN value >= 0.2 THEN 0.2
               WHEN value >= 0.1 THEN 0.1
               WHEN value >= 0.0 THEN 0.0
          END)
ORDER BY MAG
```

Comment: in combination with @justincave top answer and using `order by min(value) DESC` i've got the desired results, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this (defines 10 range start points then joins to them, grouped by range start):

```
with ranges (s) as
     ( select (rownum -1) / 10 from xmltable('0 to 5') )
select r.s as range_start
     , count(*)
from   tbl_a t
       join ranges r on t.value >= r.s
group by r.s
order by 1;
```

Test data:

```
create table tbl_a (value) as
select dbms_random.value from xmltable('1 to 100');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this. It takes advantage of the **RANGE** windowing
clause.

```sql
with t (val) as (
select 0.0 from dual union all
select 0.0 from dual union all
select 0.1 from dual union all
select 0.1 from dual union all
select 0.1 from dual union all
select 0.2 from dual union all
select 0.2 from dual union all
select 0.2 from dual union all
select 0.2 from dual union all
select 0.3 from dual union all
select 0.3 from dual union all
select 0.3 from dual union all
select 0.4 from dual union all
select 0.4 from dual union all
select 0.4 from dual union all
select 0.4 from dual union all
select 0.4 from dual union all
select 0.5 from dual union all
select 0.5 from dual
)
select val, cnt 
from (
  select val
    , count(*)over(order by val range between current row and unbounded following) cnt
  from t
  )
group by val, cnt
order by 1
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a6b950deddd4d6339219b3e2b664506)